# How to make randomsplit generate ordered items in across all splits

Tags: apache-spark

I am developing a prediction model on time-series data. I am using trainvalidationsplit in Spark to train and validate my model before testing it on an unforseen data.

Actually, in the validation phase, I need to have an ordered data based on my timestaps in input RDD (considering my RDD[timesoatmp, text]). I know trainvalidationsplit use randomsplit method which shuffle my training data. But I need to find a way when giving my trainigndata to trainvalidationsplit , and when it divided data for training and validation, the training and validation should be ordered by timestamp.

I wanted to know if is there any way to make radnomsplit generate elements across splitetd RDDs to be ordered in the follwing way. For example my RDD is (1,3,4,5,7,8), the rdd.randomsplit (0.5,0.5) should generate first RDD as (1,3,2) and the second one as (7,5,8)..the orders in each split is not important but overall the IDs (timestamps) in first split should be less than in second split.

Comment: _I know trainvalidationsplit use randomsplit method which shuffle my training data._ - it __doesn't__ shuffle.

Comment: ok, if I have a time0series traning sample as RDD is (1,3,4,5,7,8)..applying    trainvalidationsplit (0.66,0.33) on that could give something for traning (1,4,5,7,) and (3,8) for validation while, I need them to be ordered between splits so something like (1,4,3,5) and (8,7) is a coorect split set for traning and validation. I am not sure what is the meaning of shuffling.

Comment: So you're not looking for a random split at all. Just add index with `zipWithIndex` and `filter` for each range.

Comment: I need to do that within trainvalidationsplit so to be able to use pipelined a nd model tuning,selection..but trainvalidationsplit uses an internal randomsplit..should I implement my own trainvalidationsplit? I need to do it in Java..but cant find Java source codes for trainvalidationsplit.

Comment: Have you searched? Like https://github.com/apache/spark/search?l=Scala&q=%22class+TrainValidationSplit%22&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93